# Sale del bucle con muchos ceros

Tags: c, bucles

acabo de crear este código sencillo en C para que vaya dividiendo el numero entre 2 hasta que llegue al 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int num = 37;
  int i = num;

  while(i >= 1){
    printf("%d\n", num);
    num = num/2;
    i--;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Al ejecutarlo empiezan a salir ceros al final.

```
37
18
9
4
2
1
0
0
0
0
...
```

¿Como arreglo esto?

Comment: Divides num pero validas el contenido de i. Ajusta la expresión

Comment: ¿como la ajusto? No te entiendo :( @Alfabravo

Comment: De hecho no necesitas dos variables. Tienes que salir del bucle cuando num valga 0.

Comment: La condición debería ser cuando `while(num != 0)`

Comment: Los errores son el `i--;` y la condición del ciclo `while`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que en el ciclo `while` disminuyes a `i` de uno en uno. Entonces va a imprimir 0 hasta que `i` sea igual a 1 (las veces restantes a las divisiones). Si quieres solucionar esto, **no disminuyas a `i`**.

Por otro lado, definir la variable `i` en un principio fue un error, puedes usar `num` en la condición del `while`.

**Solución:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num = 37;

    while(num > 0){
        printf("%d\n",num);
        num = num / 2;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
37
18
9
4
2
1
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

Como ha dicho @SJuan76 en los comentarios, solo es necesario una variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int num = 37;

  while(num >= 1){
    printf("%d\n", num);
    num = num/2;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

De esta manera el resultado si es el deseado:

```
37
18
9
4
2
1
```